# How a callback function in javascript receives it's arguments values

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am basically learning node.js and i am not much into advance JS concepts.

```
 var fs = require('fs');
    fs.stat('/etc/passwd', function(err, stats) {
    if (err) { throw err;}
    console.log(stats);
    });
```

For the above node.js code there is an anonymous callback function, my question is how the argument values err and stats are filled up means how they get their values so that we can use them in callback function.

Comment: because fs.stat calls the function and provides the arguments.

Comment: A "callback" is a concept all of its own, node.js or otherwise.  I would suggest you first understand that and then you would how callbacks work in any circumstance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where do the parameters in a javascript callback function come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624634/where-do-the-parameters-in-a-javascript-callback-function-come-from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, functions are first class objects and hence can be passed around as objects. Here the containing function is `fs.stat` and since the containing function has the callback function in its parameter as a function definition, it can execute the callback anytime.

```
// A function that takes two parameters, the last one a callback function
function getInput (options, callback) {
    allUserData.push (options);
    callback (options);
}
```

As you can see, in the above example, getInput provides the parameters to the callback.

Hope this explanation helps

Comment: means u want to say that in fs.stat() function definition there is function which provides value to the arguments of callback function.

Comment: no. `fs.stat` gets callback as a parameter. Hence, 1)`fs.stat` invokes the passed callback and 2) `fs.stat` provides parameters to the callback it received.